# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

My android studio is failing to build right now due to the execution failed for task and it says I have more than one library with package name android.support.graphics.drawable. Here is my build.gradle (Project: DemoApp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle for (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rishavsharma.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Update your tools.build.gradle please

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar I am new to Android Studio. How do I do that?

Comment: try `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2`

Comment: like @Sagar said ->  in your project build.gradle replace `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1' ` with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2`

Comment: It gives me this error @Sagar 


Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar

Comment: Find `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`